# Closed set as singleton?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

is a closed set the same as a singleton under some topology? Or to put it differently: is there some mapping that mapped closed sets into singletons? Or also: are closed sets related somehow to discrete topology? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole space is always a closed set, so the only topological space in which all closed sets are singletons consists of a single point.

Comment: Thanks! And could it be the case that such a space (the aforementioned single point) be also a singular point (isolated singular point, so to speak)? Greetings

Comment: What do you mean by a "singular point"?

Comment: Thanks; i guess an isolated point would be a point with empty neighborhoods (within some topology or metric)